# Morphisms of $k$-algebras preserve radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

The following is the very first exercise from Assem, Simson and Skowronski's text *Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras 1*.

> **Exercise.** Let $f:A\to B$ be a homomorphism of $k$-algebras. Prove that $f(\mathrm{rad\,} A)\subseteq \mathrm{rad}\,B$.

Why is the following not a counterexample? Take any local, integral $k$-algebra $A$ (for instance $k[[x]]$) and consider the injection into its field of fractions $B$. Obviously this mapping is injective, but $B$ has trivial radical while $A$ does not.

Comment: Are you sure "radical" here means Jacobson radical rather than nilradical?

Comment: Yes (and some other characters so that this comment is long enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is correct, and the exercise is just wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eric. Reading carefully through the introduction of the text, the authors mention that they assume that their algebras are finite-dimensional. Obviously my counterexample doesn't work in this context, since a finite-dimensional integral algebra is a field. Maybe it is true in this context...

Comment: It is not true even in the finite dimensional case: consider the inclusion of the upper triangular matrices in the full matrix algebra.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks!